# gfortran doesn't work on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, gfortran

I updated my Mac to OS X 10.9 GM, then I found that gfortran does not work. 
When building any program, it shows:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.5.o
collect2: ld return 1
```

Does anyone know how I might solve this?

Comment: You can compile with ifort? Because as I see [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/library-not-found-for-lcrt1105o) you shouldn't be able to compile with ifort neither, but at least with it you have an answer.

Comment: I don't have ifort.It's not free, right?

Comment: ifort is free for non-commerical & non-academic use.

Comment: Did you update from 10.5 to 10.9?

Comment: no, from 10.8.5. Ifort for linux is free, but there's no free version for mac.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the free versions of ifort were for all platforms. In any event, you probably won't like any of my real suggestions: (a) get off Mac, (b) virtual box Linux, (c) revert back to 10.8.5, or (d) pay for a compiler ([ifort is $50](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-education-offerings#pid-2460-93) for student license, probably requires an active `.edu` email address, but not entirely sure).

Comment: Maybe it's better to get back to OS X 10.8.5...

Answer (score 4):

This problem is because OS X 10.9 has removed the /Developer directory completely where the library crt1.10.5.o used to locate. The libraries have been moved to the new Xcode directory (make sure that Xcode is also updated to the latest version 5.0.1+). I found that crt1.10.5.o is actually hidden deep in here /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/S‌​DKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib. I believe there should be a way to redirect ld automatically, but I do not know how. So for now I am using the -L flag to compile.

```
gfortran ... -L /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/S‌​DKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/lib/
```

This works for me as a temperary solution. I am also waiting for better solutions to come up.

Answer (score 3):

Gfortran has already been compiled for Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9 by http://hpc.sourceforge.net/

First, cd to the root of your Mavericks installation so the files extract recursively into the proper folders

```
cd /
sudo wget http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/hpc/gcc-4.9-bin.tar.gz
tar -xvf gcc-4.9-bin.tar.gz

gfortran --help
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems (ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o) but I discovered that they went away when I stopped using the -static flag with the gfortran command. The -static-libgcc flag seems to be OK.

Comment: I don't see where in the original question he stated he is using the -static flag?