# gfortran is not working on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: osx-mavericks, gfortran

Recently, I updated my OS X to 10.9 (Mavericks); unfortunately, gfortran stops working although I  updated Xcode command line to 5.1.1 for OS X Mavericks. Similar question has been asked sometime ago, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261001/gfortran-doesnt-work-on-mac-os-x-10-9), but I don't think so the issue is sorted out.

here is what I did:

first I removed the existing gfortran

```
bash-3.2$ sudo rm -r /usr/local/gfortran /usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Then I downloaded gfortran-4.9-bin.tar, and unzip it and installed successfully

```
bash-3.2$ gunzip gfortran-4.9-bin.tar

bash-3.2$ sudo tar xvf gfortran-4.9-bin.tar -C /

bash-3.2$ which gfortran     
/usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

but when I start running my codes , I got the following errors, e.g.

```
bash-3.2$ gfortran boolean1.f90

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_main", referenced from:
         implicit entry/start for main executable
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would be immensely grateful if anyone could guide me to solve this problem.

Comment: I am getting the same error, albeit on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. I suggest to install gfortran from packages that are available from here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran

macOS installer can be found here: http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-6.3-Sierra.dmg

Just install most recent release (using dmg file) and everything should be fine

```
! fort_sample.f90
program main
  write (*,*) 'Hello'
  stop
end
```

Compilation and execution goes smooth

```
> gfortran -o fort_sample fort_sample.f90
> ./fort_sample
 Hello
```