# How do I setup and run gfortran on Xcode 8 and Sierra

Tags: xcode8, gfortran

I modified my old fortran code to run on my Mac.  Not having an application to develop I left it alone for the last 2.5 years.  Now I have an application that I want to write but find that I am generating some error messages.  I assume that Xcode and Sierra have changed things enough that the gfortran I am trying to run is not configured correctly, or they just don't match.

I know Xcode was not written for fortran but some of my old code is in a project.  I have no idea if was an attempt to use it as a development spot or just a holder for the code.  Can someone point me in a direction that will get me going again.  I am presently trying to use Terminal but without full success.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are using terminal, what version of gfortran are you using, and how are you compiling your code. I'd suggest that via terminal is probably the right way to go

Comment: I am using fortran version 4.8.1 and using terminal for compiling.  This is what I got when I tried to compile and run using this command
gfortran helloworld.for

gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.6.0
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I was not getting the library not found so I must have changed something when I was experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get your code running is to compile gfortran. It will work just fine with macOS Sierra - I have tested it in the past.

All you have to do is to go here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran

And compile the code. Simply download sources:

https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranSource

```
> ./configure
> make
```

and that's it. You can also take a look here:

[gfortran is not working on Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501128/gfortran-is-not-working-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/44729407#44729407)

Comment: does this assume the target machine already has the XCode command line tools?

Comment: I am using fortran version 4.8.1 and using terminal for compiling.  This is what I got when I tried to compile and run using this command
gfortran helloworld.for

gfortran: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘16.6.0
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I was not getting the library not found so I must have changed something when I was experimenting.